# why failed to load module script error when hosting chrome devtools frontend by Nginx?

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome, nginx, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm developing a frontend app with Vue.js, and I want to embed [Chrome DevTools frontend](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend) into it, but I met with an error when navigating to `/devtools/inspector.html` after I finished it.

Firstly, I build chrome devtools frontend from source code, and get `out/Default/gen/front_end/` folder, then I put it into `public/devtools` in frontend app project source code.

After that, I make a docker imaga, in which using Nginx to host the frontend app.

```
# build stage
FROM node:16 AS build-stage

COPY ./ /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install && npm run build


# production stage
FROM nginx:stable AS production-stage

RUN mkdir /app
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /app
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Everything is fine when I test this docker image on my local develop machine.

[image]

But when I deploy it in production mode, everything is fine if I navigate normal frontend app pages, but when I navigate to `/devtools/inspector.html`, the page turns out to be blank and the console shows the following error.

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script 
but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". 
Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

[image]

I don't quite understand what's going wrong here, and I'm sure the `out/Default/gen/front_end/` folder is OK to use, for I tested putting this folder into `resources/static` folder of a simple Springboot app, and `/devtools/inspector.html` is OK to show.

Thanks for paying attention to this question, any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Problem fixed.

The reason is that, the `.gitignore` file blocks some files in devtools frontend, so the devtools frontend in git  repository is incomplete, lots of files are missing.